# php reading header into array from cached curl file

Tags: php, caching, curl

I am using zebra_curl / curl to cache webpages to a cache folder, and I'm then wanting to access what looks like the header information as it holds the original url and other information inside which i need when processing the cached files.

At first i thought it was json, and when using json_decode i wasn't getting anything back, I've done a bit of searching on the internet, i can find lots about dumping to a cache file but nothing about reading a cache file.

below is a sample, i have stripped the actual html webpage out for the purpose of this post.

```
    O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"info";a:27:{s:12:"original_url";s:65:"http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00OYTAQAM/ref=sr_1_1?m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE";s:3:"url";s:65:"http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00OYTAQAM/ref=sr_1_1?m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE";s:12:"content_type";s:29:"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";s:9:"http_code";i:200;s:11:"header_size";i:1021;s:12:"request_size";i:191;s:8:"filetime";i:-1;s:17:"ssl_verify_result";i:0;s:14:"redirect_count";i:0;s:10:"total_time";d:1.0510690000000000310365066980011761188507080078125;s:15:"namelookup_time";d:2.300000000000000001799775606325937360452371649444103240966796875E-5;s:12:"connect_time";d:0.036834999999999999686917107055705855600535869598388671875;s:16:"pretransfer_time";d:0.036865000000000001934008508897022693417966365814208984375;s:11:"size_upload";d:0;s:13:"size_download";d:111412;s:14:"speed_download";d:105998;s:12:"speed_upload";d:0;s:23:"download_content_length";d:-1;s:21:"upload_content_length";d:0;s:18:"starttransfer_time";d:0.151627000000000011770140417866059578955173492431640625;s:13:"redirect_time";d:0;s:12:"redirect_url";s:0:"";s:10:"primary_ip";s:13:"178.236.6.251";s:8:"certinfo";a:0:{}s:12:"primary_port";i:80;s:8:"local_ip";s:13:"192.168.0.102";s:10:"local_port";i:54085;}s:7:"headers";a:2:{s:12:"last_request";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:14:"Request Method";s:55:"GET /dp/B00OYTAQAM/ref=sr_1_1?m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE HTTP/1.1";s:10:"User-Agent";s:50:"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.2)";s:4:"Host";s:16:"www.amazon.co.uk";s:6:"Accept";s:3:"*/*";s:15:"Accept-Encoding";s:12:"gzip,deflate";}}s:9:"responses";a:1:{i:0;a:16:{s:6:"Status";s:15:"HTTP/1.1 200 OK";s:4:"Date";s:29:"Tue, 02 Jun 2015 19:02:52 GMT";s:6:"Server";s:6:"Server";s:6:"pragma";s:8:"no-cache";s:10:"x-amz-id-1";s:20:"1BSMQ0WW03GTYQ9G5KY3";s:3:"p3p";s:180:"policyref="http://www.amazon.co.uk/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="CAO DSP LAW CUR ADM IVAo IVDo CONo OTPo OUR DELi PUBi OTRi BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA HEA PRE LOC GOV OTC "";s:8:"x-sap-pg";s:30:"video_games_display_on_website";s:13:"cache-control";s:8:"no-cache";s:15:"x-frame-options";s:10:"SAMEORIGIN";s:7:"expires";s:2:"-1";s:10:"x-amz-id-2";s:64:"tlcbwlgcLZUV2WrqsdudobEcS3jz5E5mMdCIRDXhNksTxmF1Y3StAaO+fmghPfux";s:4:"Vary";s:26:"Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";s:16:"Content-Encoding";s:4:"gzip";s:12:"Content-Type";s:29:"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";s:10:"Set-cookie";s:99:"session-id=279-5866789-0523540; path=/; domain=.amazon.co.uk; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 00:00:01 GMT";s:17:"Transfer-Encoding";s:7:"chunked";}}}s:4:"body";s:475134:"



    !!!HTML CODE HERE!!




    ";s:8:"response";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"CURLE_OK";i:1;i:0;}}
```

Comment: Looks like `serialize()`'d data. Have you tried using [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it?

Comment: not heard of un/serialize before, just looked it up and got it working now so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

used unserialize() after @Jon Stirling recognised format